# Django model choice field from another model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my **models.py**, I have two classes, `ChoiceList` and `SampleModel` as below

```
class ChoiceList(models.Model):
    choice=models.CharField(max_length=15)

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    CHOICELIST=ChoiceList.objects.all()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    your_choice=models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=ChoiceList)
```

I need to add `your_choice` field data only from `ChoiceList` instances. Can I add data in that way ?

When I doing this way, I got error as `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: rest_api_ChoiceList`
Can anyone solve the problem ?

Comment: why are you not using [ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you should use [ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

```
your_choice=models.ForeignKey(ChoiceList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Would it not lose the Select widget if oen uses ForeignField instead of ChoiceField?